# The application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I have been encountering the following error when I try to launch Batman Arkham City;

> The application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b

- I have tried reinstalling the Game.
- Installed xlive.dll files

Not sure which DLL file is

System Config

```
 OS : Windows 7 64 bit
 GPU: Nvidia 285 GTX
```

Answer (score 1):

Solutions

install latest GPU drivers

update DirectX to the latest your GPU supports

install/update .NET Framework (4.0)

download and install DirectX Redist (March 2009) from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/resultsForProduct.aspx?displaylang=en&productID=9C954C37-1ED1-4846-8A7D-85FC422D1388

install the Microsoft DirectX End-User Runtime